# Minimize LPP using graphical method [ operational research ]

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

Question:
Minimize z = 2x + 6y

Subject to 
2x + y >= 2;
3x + 4y <= 12

x,y >=0

Is min z = 2 the right answer ? if not how do i solve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\min_{x,y}\quad & 2x+6y
\\2x +y &\geq 2
\\3x+4y&\leq 12
\\x,y &\geq0
\end{align}
The easiest way to solve this graphically would be to list down the corner points and the value of the objective function at each.

If you do that, you can see that $(1,0)$ has the lowest objective value of $2$ (As you pointed out). And since the optimal solution of a Linear Programming Problem always lies on the corner points, this is the global optimum of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also draw some level curves of the objective funtion, $c = 2x + 6y$, for some constant $c$ and you will see that the minimum value of $c$ which is feasible will lie at a corner point like the answer above.